# Do not show message of TempData in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, message, break, tempdata

This is my base controller class:

```
public class SiteBaseController : Controller
{
    protected string SuccessMessage = "SuccessMessage";
    protected string ErrorMessage = "ErrorMessage";
    protected string WarningMessage = "WarningMessage";
    protected string InfoMessage = "InfoMessage";

    public IActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and write the massage in `_Notification.cshtml`

```
@if (TempData["WarningMessage"] != null)
{
<script>
    ShowMessage('warn', '@TempData["WarningMessage"]', 'warning');
</script>
}
```

When I use it on my controller, it does not show my message that I set.

My controller code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var result = await _userService.RegisterUser(registerUserViewModel);

    switch (result)
    {
        case RegisterUserResult.UserExist:
            TempData[WarningMessage] = "User Exist";
            break;
        .....
    }
}
```

when I set break point i see get this value but dont show on site
it is myy error. I have some problem in Js

[image]

Comment: Hi @hasti.au,  `When I use it on my controller, it does not show my message that I set.` From this description, it seems you want to use the TempData written from the view. How do you write the TempData? I cannot see how you write to the TempData.

Comment: Hi. update the question. I write temp data , with a JS code for show in in all sites, when I set break point , it works and give the message  but doesn't show message on the site after register

Comment: there are some switch case:
 
                  
                        TempData[SuccessMessage] = "user Exist";
                   
                        ;